# Switch Dataset in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report in **SSRS** that uses multiple data-sets in it.

For a certain table in the report, I want to point it to a different data-set.

But it is grayed-out as shown in the picture below.

Please assist me.
[image]

Comment: By any chance does your table(s) reside under one `List, this would not allow you to set different `datasets`.

Comment: Yes all the tables are inserted inside one List. The reason being that I want to group everything with an ID that is found in all the datasets.

Comment: the reason for many datasets is that some fields I need to display are located different tables and thus different datasets

Comment: You may then need to query the tables into the same data set to be able to use them inside the same tablix, if you post your two queries, and some example output we should be able to help